# How do I make join see my objects as strings?

Tags: python, string, text

I am trying to build a program in an object oriented fashion. My `Phrase` object can contain one or more `Noun` objects. When you cast the `Phrase` to string, `join` the `nouns` list together like this

```
@property
def nouns_text(self) -> str:
    return ' '.join(self.nouns)
```

But this raises the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "jovin.py", line 173, in <module>
    print(subject)
  File "jovin.py", line 131, in __str__
    return str(self.phrase)
  File "jovin.py", line 82, in __str__
    return str(self.text)
  File "jovin.py", line 78, in text
    text:str = f'{self.adverbs_text} {self.adjectives_text} {self.nouns_text}'
  File "jovin.py", line 74, in nouns_text
    return ' '.join(self.nouns)
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, Pronoun found
```

It appears that `join` will only work with objects that *ARE* strings, not objects that *behave like* strings.

I can solve this problem by doing this

`' '.join([str(x) for x in self.nouns])`

or by creating a `staticmethod` to do it

```
@staticmethod
def convert_list_to_text(self, part_of_speech):
    return ' '.join([str(x) for x in part_of_speech])

@property
def adverbs_text(self) -> str:
    return self.convert_list_to_text(self.adverbs)

@property
def nouns_text(self) -> str:
    return self.convert_list_to_text(self.nouns)
```

But it *feels* like a hack either way.

Can someone either explain another way to do this, or why this is the right way to go?

Comment: What is the definition of `Noun`? If it behaves like a string, it should have the [__str__ and __repr__ method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1436703/13253010).

Comment: It does have __str__ and __repr__ methods. (The representation of the object is __str__)

Answer (score 0):

```
' '.join([str(x) for x in self.nouns])
```

This is good, and it's what you should do. There's one slight optimization you can do. Rather than constructing an intermediate list, you can use a generator expression.

```
' '.join(str(x) for x in self.nouns)
```

Or, if you prefer `map` calls,

```
' '.join(map(str, self.nouns))
```

Either is acceptable and they're basically equivalent.